# Sort nil to the end of an array of optional strings

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, option-type

If I have an array of optional strings, and I want to sort it in ascending order with nils at the beginning, I can do it easily in a single line:

```
["b", nil, "a"].sorted{ $0 ?? "" < $1 ?? "" } // [nil, "a", "b"]
```

But there doesn't seem to be any similarly easy solution to sort nils to the **end** of the array. It can be easily done with most other simple data types, for instance:

```
[2, nil, 1].sorted{ $0 ?? Int.max < $1 ?? Int.max } // [1, 2, nil]
```

For doubles you can do the same with `greatestFiniteMagnitude`, for dates you can use `distantFuture`.  Is there any kind of equivalent for strings, or any other concise way of doing this so I can avoid writing a bunch of messy conditionals?

Comment: use `"\u{ffff}"` instead `""`

Comment: @holex: What if the string is "" aka `"\u{1f600}"` ? How does that compare to `"\u{ffff}"`  ? It might work by chance, but I would not recommend using “magic values.”

Comment: @MartinR, the idea was showing a potential _high-end_ unicode value here, not an _exact_ value – but agreed there are more elegant solutions (like yours for instance) but most of the devs can't comprehend that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can provide a custom comparator which considers `nil`
as larger than any non-nil value:

```
let array = ["b", nil, "a", nil]

let sortedArray = array.sorted { (lhs, rhs) -> Bool in
    switch (lhs, rhs) {
    case let(l?, r?): return l < r // Both lhs and rhs are not nil
    case (nil, _): return false    // Lhs is nil
    case (_?, nil): return true    // Lhs is not nil, rhs is nil
    }
}

print(sortedArray) // [Optional("a"), Optional("b"), nil, nil]
```

This works with any array of optional comparable elements, and avoids
the usage of “magical large” values. The comparator can be implemented
as a generic function:

```
func compareOptionalsWithLargeNil<T: Comparable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool {
    switch (lhs, rhs) {
    case let(l?, r?): return l < r // Both lhs and rhs are not nil
    case (nil, _): return false    // Lhs is nil
    case (_?, nil): return true    // Lhs is not nil, rhs is nil
    }
}

print(["b", nil, "a", nil].sorted(by: compareOptionalsWithLargeNil))
// [Optional("a"), Optional("b"), nil, nil]

print([2, nil, 1].sorted(by: compareOptionalsWithLargeNil))
// [Optional(1), Optional(2), nil]

print([3.0, nil, 1.0].sorted(by: compareOptionalsWithLargeNil))
// [Optional(1.0), Optional(3.0), nil]

print([Date(), nil, .distantPast, nil, .distantFuture].sorted(by: compareOptionalsWithLargeNil))
// [Optional(0000-12-30 00:00:00 +0000), Optional(2018-11-22 13:56:03 +0000),
//  Optional(4001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000), nil, nil]
```

Comment: Why choose this name `WithLargeNil`?

Comment: @Carpsen90: Because it considers nil as *larger* than any other value, and I could not think of a better name :)

Answer (score 1):

One `nil` is indistinguishable from another. So if you have a working solution that happens to sort as you desire except that `nil` entries wind up at the start, use it and then remove the `nil` entries and append the same number of `nil` entries to the end.

Example:

```
    var arr : [String?] = [nil, "b", nil, "a", nil]
    arr = arr.sorted{ $0 ?? "" < $1 ?? "" }
    if let ix = arr.firstIndex(where: {$0 != nil}) {
        arr = arr.suffix(from: ix) + Array(repeating: nil, count: ix)
    }
    // [Optional("a"), Optional("b"), nil, nil, nil]
```

Comment: `arr` is already a `var`, so `arr.sort { ... }` instead of `arr = arr.sorted{ ... }`

Answer (score 1):

Your example with `Int` gives a clue. If we had a max string value, we could plug that in.

This works for strings that contain only alphabetic characters:

```
let maxString = "~"
["b", nil, "a"].sorted{ $0 ?? maxString < $1 ?? maxString }
```

Or simply:

```
["b", nil, "a"].sorted{ $0 ?? "~" < $1 ?? "~" }
```